# Input validating forms Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation, symfony-forms

I've got an Integer field in Symfony form, which represents quantity - ofcourse it should be unable to pass the value equal or less than 0, so I've validated form in Entity and Form.

But - It's validated only when form is already sent. Is there any built-in method to validate form on input? I know that propably i would need to write own JS function to provide this, but I don't want to repeat someone others job :)

Comment: Please show your code and the rendered HTML. For example on https://jsfiddle.net/dwhtmu0s/ if I enter the `a` value and submit the form, Firefox displays a warning.

Comment: I know! :D But I wonder if there is a chance to automatically generate JS code to validate that form.

Comment: Your best shot would probably be regex. With regex you can check the input on the client side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution.

To validate Symfony form on HTML side, you can just add an attribute to input field, reference: https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_form_attributes.asp

So, you form field should look like:

```
->add('quantity', IntegerType::class, ['label' => false,
       'constraints' => new GreaterThan(array('value' => 0)),                
       'attr' => array(
            'min'   => '0',
        )
     ])
```

Comment: You should add `NotEmpty` constraint as well before. By default, if the value is null, Symfony validators skip validation.

Answer (score 2):

Use pattern and min on your input. HTML should prevent form submit as long as the pattern isn't matched. (Careful, isn't doens't prevent submit if you're usin Javascript/Ajax to submit)

```
$builder->add('input_name', TextType::class, array(
    'attr'=>array(
        'pattern'=>'^[1-9][0-9]*' // 1 and above
        'min'=>'1'
    )
));
```

I'm using a TextType to remove the arrows in the input.
If you want to keep them, use NumberType.

Answer (score 1):

A little addition, if you want to make sure a user can only enter a number you can add this bit of js to your code.

```
->add('quantity', NumberType::class, [ 'attr' => 
[
'oninput' => "this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');"
] ])
```